# How to manually create a view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have those translated urls:

```
url(r'^$', p_views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(_(r'^vente-groupee/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$'),
    p_views.VenteGroupeeDetailView.as_view(), name='vente_groupee'),
```

I've made this *temporary* redirect in index view:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'produits/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'liste_produits'

    # !!! Temporary just to sell one item for now
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        langue_courante = translation.get_language()
        obj = get_object_or_404(Description,
                                langue__locale__exact=langue_courante,
                                ventes_groupees__pk=1,)
        return redirect(reverse('vente_groupee',
                                kwargs={'slug': obj.slug}))
```

My problem is: because it makes a redirect, the url in the browser changes, and *I dont want that*.

What should be the best way to display a "`vente_groupee`" view as the "root" = "**`/`**" of the website?

Comment: Why do you redirect?

Comment: It's written in my question, in the comments of my code: **Temporary just to sell one item for now**. **`Plus`** I need to properly get the url base on a specific item that's why i just cant make the view **`/`** render directly through a `vente_groupee` view (it needs a parameter and **`/`** doesn't have one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're after. If you just want to make the root URL always use that view with a hard-coded slug, you can do that:

```
url(r'^$', p_views.VenteGroupeeDetailView.as_view(slug="my_item_id"), name='index')
```